# How to merge two columns and separate them with comma in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Original table:

[image]

The attached image of the original table is a de-normalized table, created using a view which repeats customer names and order Ids.

Desired outcome:

[image]

I would like to keep the `OrderId` unique and merge products for each order in one row and separate it by comma.

Comment: From my experience this question or how to split comma separated column is asked every day.

Comment: No, no, no, no! That is even worse. Use another table!

Comment: @juergend First you should explain what is **First Normal Form** and why **non-atomic values** are bad

Comment: @lad2025: Yes, in an answer. This was just a comment.

Comment: Its enough to put me in a coma...

Ill get me coat

Comment: if it is for a display in a program it could be quite legit to use this method (although normally it is done programmatically and not from the sql side as far as I'm aware). For use just inside the sql itself is rather unique.  @lokapedia maybe you should add a bit why it is necessary to use this different display inside sql? (as normally the , display is used in the client applications and not sql itself)